# EmberJS Second level of service are not injected when calling from template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, action

When calling a service function from a template e.g. `onClick={{action myFirstLevel.hello}}`, the services which should be injected into `myFirstLevel` stay `undefined`.

The call through a component action is working.

```
<button onClick={{action myFirstLevel.hello}}>Hello Service</button>
<button onClick={{action 'hello'}}>Hello Action</button>


App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyFirstLevelService = Ember.Service.extend({
  mySecondLevel: Ember.inject.service(),
  hello: function() {
    console.log('Hello first level');
    this.get('mySecondLevel').hello();
  }
});

App.MySecondLevelService = Ember.Service.extend({
  hello: function() {
    console.log('Hello second level');
  }
});

App.MyButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  myFirstLevel: Ember.inject.service(),

  actions: {
    hello:  function() {
      this.get('myFirstLevel').hello();
    }
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/conaxaheno/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

`myFirstLevel.hello` function will be called through `MyButtonComponent` this context, so when you do `this.get('mySecondLevel')` in service it will return `undefined`, so to make it work you should include `mySecondLevel` service into Component

```
App.MyButtonComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  myFirstLevel: Ember.inject.service(),
  mySecondLevel: Ember.inject.service(),
  actions: {
    hello:  function() {
      this.get('myFirstLevel').hello();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hack. However it is not recommended unless you absolutely have to do it. I believe that in your situation the optimal way would be to use a second button option, but you can take your chances if you are absolutely sure on what you are doing:

```
App.MyFirstLevelService = Ember.Service.extend({
  mySecondLevel: Ember.inject.service(),
  hello: function() {
    console.log('Hello first level');
    Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('service:my-first-level').get('mySecondLevel').hello()
  }
});
```

This function would be actually called when you click the button but it would be called with the context of component which is not what you want as when you target `this` you access component scope instead.

Another option is

```
App.MyFirstLevelService = Ember.Service.extend({
      mySecondLevel: Ember.inject.service(),
      hello: function() {
        console.log('Hello first level');
        this.get('myFirstLevel.mySecondLevel').hello()
      }
});
```

In it you would avoid messing with owners but it is still completely unreadable. The best thing you can do is just stick to defining actions on the component scope and calling them from your template. Those actions in turn can get the services for you with any depth and trigger functions on them.

Answer (score 0):

@kumkanillam was right, the context is wrong. To set it, it's possible to use `target=` but it does not seems to work with `onClick=...`.

So the correct synthax is `<button {{action myFirstLevel.hello target=myFirstLevel}}>Hello Service</button>`

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/14334